# Some avatars have no pictures for me

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture

It occurred many times for me that when I'm looking a question, the OP's avatar is nothing (like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417852/interaction-axes-in-ms-excel)). I also check his or her [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4743270/ippolit-vazovsky), and there the avatar is nothing as well. Then I check his or her [Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4743270/ippolit-vazovsky?tab=activity). In my mind, if a new user signed up to this site he or she will have a default avatar generated by SO. If the user can remove his or her avatar, I want to know why and who.

[image]

I usually use Firefox, latest version.

The issue occurs with these users:

- [carson moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4685553/carson-moore)
- [tai huynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4675961/tai-huynh)
- [doml the bread](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641605/doml-the-bread)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. The profile shows an avatar picture? I'm using Google Chrome, Version 41.0.2272.118 m

Comment: F*cebook is blocked on your network.

Comment: @Will yes, it's blocked on my network.

Comment: The Aristocrats.

Comment: googleusercontent.com too (carson moore)

Comment: Oh, I’m being mentioned in a meta post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The images that those users use for their profile are on sites that are blocked by many workplace and school web filters: [Facebook](http://facebook.com) and the [Google User Content](http://www.googleusercontent.com) CDN, which hosts images from Google accounts.

Presumably, they don't show up for you because those sites are blocked and so calls to them for images will be unsuccessful.